# RISC-V assembly lui?

Tags: assembly, assembler, risc-v

In RISC-V assembly I wrote:

```
addi s0,x0,0x20000
```

Is this legal such that the assembler will prove the command and make it work right or I'm forced to change it to:

```
lui s0,0x20
```

Can someone kindly explain what `lui` does?

Comment: I strongly suggest that for questions like this you write little snippets of code and try them out.  Even if you don't have a RISC V chip lying around, there should be emulators.  The *reason* I suggest this is that you generally learn the answer to your question, plus about half a dozen other questions -- and their answers, eventually -- that you didn't know to ask.

Comment: what part of the risc-v documentation do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this won't work because ADDI can only add 12-bit immediate values which are sign-extended to 32 bits. RISC-V is not like ARM where almost any immediate value can be shifted before it's used. Therefore with ADDI you can add 0x000-0x7FF or subtract 0x001-0x800. The limitation to 12-bit immediate values is because of the encoding of ADDI:

[image: RISC-V ADDI encoding]
However, ADDI with x0 as the source register is valid for loading smaller immediate values, so you could do `ADDI s0, x0, #0x123`, for example. NOP is also implemented this way, and is just a pseudo-instruction for `ADDI x0, x0, #0x0`. Other forms of NOP (for example adding 0 to a register other than x0) are considered non-canonical and are not recommended because they may be redefined to be a different, meaningful instruction in the future.

As for LUI, it loads a 20-bit immediate value into the upper 20 bits of a (32-bit) register and fills in other 12 bits with 0's. Notice how you can use LUI to set the upper 20 bits of a register and then ADDI set the lower 12 bits, thus loading a 32-bit constant into the register with just two instructions.